# Faulty wordpress post link (leads to wrong direction)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've got a post on my site running WP 4.7.2 with permalink http://www.pimpf.ru/discography/depeche-mode/video/101/ and dirty link http://www.pimpf.ru/?p=1780.

Any of the above links lead to `http://www.pimpf.ru/discography/depeche-mode/video/video-singles-collection/101/`.

It seems WP adds `video-singles-collection/` between `video/` and `101` due to some MySQL error.

Where should I dig my WP database to correct this error?

So far I've tried to delete the `101` post and create the new one, and rename its permalink to `101-video`. Both with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because your faulty post's permanent link contains only digits. Try to rename it to something like `one-zero-one` or `1o1`. That should help.

Comment: Both your variants work. Thank you very much! Strangely I've renamed the post to 101-video again and now it opens correctly. May be it required some interim renames, who knows. But renaming it back to `101` end up with the wrong post, so it is definitely the digits only problem. Thank you.